# Rails Routes: as-block and device_for block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

According to devise documentation, we can override the default session paths using the following:

```
as :user do
   get 'login', to: 'users/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
   post 'login', to: 'users/sessions#create', as: :user_session
   delete 'logout', to: 'users/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
end
```

This will generate the following routes:

```
Helper Path                   URL        Controller
new_user_session_path        /login      users/sessions#new
user_session_path            /login      users/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path    /logout     users/sessions#destroy
```

However, without wrapping the defined path inside an `as-block` or a `devise_scope` block, such as the one below, **we produce the same exact routes**.

```
get 'login', to: 'users/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
post 'login', to: 'users/sessions#create', as: :user_session
delete 'logout', to: 'users/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
```

My question is, why do we even need the `as-block` / device_for block? Why not just define it directly? What is the function and benefit of the `as-block`?

Answer (score 0):

RESTful routes for devise looks like: `devise_for :users ...`

In any case, the `as` is equivalent to the `devise_scope` one, and they are designed for specifying your custom routes.

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) on this question.

Comment: Yes, I know that they are used to specify custom routes. My question is why do i need to wrap it inside an `as` block when it produces the same result even when i do not wrap it inside the `as` block

Comment: @Tikiboy Because in the r/ror you can achieve the goal in different ways. But I think the way with `as` is more readable, moreover: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#routing

Comment: @MichaelArkhipov - you're saying it's purely decorative.  That's not a very satisfying answer.